# Trouble with ActionCable in React 18 upgrade: TypeError "consumer.disconnect is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I recently updated my application from React 17 to React 18 and encountered an issue with a failing test. The error message I'm seeing is:

`TypeError: consumer.disconnect is not a function`

This error is related to a test that involves an action cable handling real-time updates. Here's the relevant test code:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createConsumer } from 'actioncable';
import { ActioncableProvider } from 'providers/ActioncableProvider/ActioncableProvider';
import { getApiToken } from 'helpers/apiToken/apiToken';

jest.mock('actioncable', () => ({
  createConsumer: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('helpers/apiToken/apiToken', () => ({
  getApiToken: jest.fn(),
}));

const addSubProtocol = jest.fn();

const renderWithProvider = (ui: JSX.Element) =>
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<ActioncableProvider />}>
          <Route path='/' element={ui} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </MemoryRouter>,
  );

describe('<ActioncableProvider />', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    (createConsumer as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({ addSubProtocol });
    (getApiToken as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue('valid-api-token');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('renders the children', () => {
    renderWithProvider(<div>Children</div>);
    expect(screen.getByText('Children')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('sets up the actioncable consumer', () => {
    renderWithProvider(<div />);
    expect(createConsumer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(createConsumer).toHaveBeenCalledWith('ws://localhost:3010/cable');
    expect(addSubProtocol).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(addSubProtocol).toHaveBeenCalledWith('valid-api-token');
  });
});
```

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Consumer, createConsumer } from 'actioncable';
import config from 'config';
import { getApiToken } from 'helpers/apiToken/apiToken';

const ActioncableContext = createContext<Consumer | undefined>(undefined);

function ActioncableProvider() {
  const actioncableUrl = config.actioncableUrl[process.env.NODE_ENV as Environment];
  const consumer = createConsumer(actioncableUrl);
  consumer.addSubProtocol(getApiToken());

  useEffect(() => () => consumer.disconnect(), []);

  return (
    <ActioncableContext.Provider value={useMemo(() => consumer, [])}>
      <Outlet />
    </ActioncableContext.Provider>
  );
}

const useActioncableContext = () => {
  const consumer = useContext(ActioncableContext);
  if (!consumer) throw new Error('No consumer found when calling useActioncableContext.');
  return consumer;
};

export { ActioncableContext, ActioncableProvider, useActioncableContext };
```

I suspect the issue might be related to how React 18 handles context or hooks. The error seems to be occurring in the useEffect cleanup code where consumer.disconnect() is called.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem when upgrading to React 18? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are changing return type of `createConsumer` to `{ addSubProtocol }`. There is no `disconnect` in this object